# Weighted Analogue of Mean Value Property

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f$ be a harmonic function defined on a planar disk $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and continuous on $\partial B$. For which probability measures $\mu$ on $\partial B$ is it true that
$$\int_{\partial B } \! f(s) \, d\mu(s) = f(x_0)$$
for some $x_0 \in \overline{B}$?

Let me say explicitly that the point of the question is that $x_0$ is allowed to depend on $f$ as well as $\mu$, since otherwise the Poisson kernel is obviously the only solution.

Comment: If $f$ is one dimensional it's trivial: As $\operatorname{inf}_{\partial B} f(s) \le \int_{\partial B} f(s) d\mu(s) \le \operatorname{sup}_{\partial B} f(s)$, f is continuous and $\partial B$ is compact we have that the value of the integral is taken for some point between the point where $f$ takes it's maximum and it's minimum.

Comment: I noted your edit, but I meant that if $f$ itself is of more than one dimension, that $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ where $n>1$.

Comment: @skyking Thanks, of course you're right...